# Context-sensitive length "units" in LaTeX

Tags: lengths

I would like to include in some macro a separating space that is "context-sensitive" (in the sense that when the macro is called, for example, inside a subscript, the separating space reduces accordingly).

Is there any specific command producing such behavior?

Otherwise, I am tempted to use the command `\phantom` to simulate it, say:

```
\newcommand{\contextseparate}[2]{#1 \phantom{M} #2}
```

Is this last approach acceptable? (For some reason it looks bad to me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you embed the macro definition in `\ThisStyle{}` from the `scalerel` package, it recognizes `\LMpt` and `\LMex` as lengths that scale with the Local-Math size.

More particularly, the scaling factors for `\LMpt` and `\LMex` are predefined (but can be reset) as

```
\def\scriptstyleScaleFactor{0.7}
\def\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor{0.5}
```

Obviously, the scale factor is 1 for `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle`.  The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\contextseparate}[2]{\ThisStyle{#1\kern1.5\LMex#2}} 
\begin{document}
$\contextseparate{A}{B}$\par
$\scriptstyle\contextseparate{A}{B}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\contextseparate{A}{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you ever need to recall the current math style in a place where it would otherwise be inaccessible (such as inside a box), you can invoke `\SavedStyle` to recover whatever style was active at the onset of the associated `\ThisStyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\contextseparate}[2]{\ThisStyle{\fboxsep=0pt%
  #1\fbox{$\phantom{\SavedStyle m}$}#2}} 
\begin{document}
$\contextseparate{A}{B}$\par
$\scriptstyle\contextseparate{A}{B}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\contextseparate{A}{B}$
\end{document}
```

[image]